# Custom Wordpress Theme php is processed in source code but not on page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm in the process of creating a custom WP theme for my portfolio. I cannot find a solution to this issue anywhere. I've set up a custom page with a loop to display my portfolio posts in a grid format on my homepage, [www.gregoryrich.com](http://www.gregoryrich.com). I want my posts to display in full text (not in a grid format) on [www.gregoryrich.com/blog](http://www.gregoryrich.com/blog) where I am using my default index template. I've gotten the grid to work, but the blog page is not displaying my posts. The strange thing is that when I view my source, the post content is displaying in the source code, but it's just not displaying on the page. I've adjusted the reading settings, reset my permalinks many times, deactivated all of my plugins, and even reinstalled Wordpress completely. It seems like I might be missing something obvious, but I cannot figure it out and it's really frustrated me. Any help anyone can offer would be extremely appreciated.

My grid loop:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Home
*/
?>


`<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="content" class="group">

   <div id="gridcontainer">
    <?php
    $counter = 1; //start counter

    $grids = 2; //Grids per row

    global $query_string; //Need this to make pagination work


    /*Setting up our custom query (In here we are setting it to show 12 posts per page and eliminate all sticky posts) */
    query_posts($query_string . '&caller_get_posts=1&posts_per_page=12');


    if(have_posts()) :  while(have_posts()) :  the_post();
    ?>
    <?php
    //Show the left hand side column
    if($counter == 1) :
    ?>
                <div class="griditemleft">
                    <div class="postimage">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('category-thumbnail'); ?></a>
                    </div>
                    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                </div>
    <?php
    //Show the right hand side column
    elseif($counter == $grids) :
    ?>
    <div class="griditemright">
                    <div class="postimage">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('category-thumbnail'); ?></a>
                    </div>
                    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <?php
    $counter = 0;
    endif;
    ?>
    <?php
    $counter++;
    endwhile;
    //Pagination can go here if you want it.
    endif;
    ?>
   </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>`
```

And my index page loop:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="content" class="group">

<article>

<?php // Display blog posts on any page @ http://m0n.co/l
        $temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null;
        $wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('showposts=5' . '&paged='.$paged);
        while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <div class="post-header">
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </div><!--end post header-->
    <div class="entry clear">
        <?php if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <?php echo get_template_part(); ?><?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php edit_post_link(); ?>
        <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
    </div><!--end entry-->
  </div><!--end post-->

<?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php if ($paged > 1) { ?>

        <nav id="nav-posts">
            <div class="prev"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Previous Posts'); ?></div>
            <div class="next"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Posts &raquo;'); ?></div>
        </nav>

        <?php } else { ?>

        <nav id="nav-posts">
            <div class="prev"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Previous Posts'); ?></div>
        </nav>

        <?php } ?>

        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

</article>

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: if the html is visible in `view source`, but not rendering on page, then you need to look for broken/invalid html, or bad css rules.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am going through each page now. Still haven't been able to locate the problem, and it does validate, but I haven't finished yet.

Comment: Apparently the "font-size: 0" tag I had applied to my container div was causing this problem. Thanks again for your help.